# Outgoing Tomcat SSL Connection

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, keystore

I have a Java application being served by Tomcat on Server A.  Server A needs to make an SSL connection to Server B.  As long as I have the root certificate in cacerts on Server A for the CA that issued Server B's server certificate I don't need to install Server B's certificate on Server A.

True or false?

Currently, Server B's certificate is installed on Server A.  I want to remove it because I don't think it needs to be there.  Will this disable the SSL connection between Server A and Server B?

Comment: 'True or false?': true. As long as you have any of the signer certificates in the truststore you don't need the server certificate, or any certificate below that signer certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. If it wasn't the case then everyone would need to install everyones certificate in order to establish SSL connections. The CA root cert is what makes it so we don't need to do this. Your understanding is correct.